# Homebrew error: "ruby@2.7 is not a valid keg"

Tags: ruby, homebrew, ruby-2.7

Every time I try to install or uninstall something using Homebrew, I got an error below.

```
"Error: /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7 is not a valid keg"
```

I checked symlink by typing "ls -ld /usr/local/opt /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7", and got results below.

```
drwxrwxr-x  183 aiden0206  admin  5856 10  3 20:53 /usr/local/opt
lrwxr-xr-x    1 aiden0206  admin    24 10  3 20:53 /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7 -> ../Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.4
```

There seems to be no problem. The ruby@2.7 in /usr/local/opt correctly points to the /Cellar directory. Is there any other cause of the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try SuperUser and please mention system type.

Comment: What does `brew doctor` say?